# Microsoft BotFrameWork styleSet with hideUploadButton

Tags: javascript, html, botframework, chatbot, implementation

Hi I am new to Microsoft's Bot Framework, pardon me for my questions.

I was trying out to change the styling for the chatbots and I came upon an issue where I was not able to disable my upload button via styleSet.

```js
const styleOptions = {
        hideUploadButton: true,
        bubbleBackground: "red",
        bubbleBorderStyle: "solid",
        bubbleBorderRadius: "10px",
        bubbleFromUserBackground: "#5ce9ff",
        bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: "10px",
        groupTimeStamp: 3000,
        emojiSet: true,
        timestampFormat: 'relative',
        timestampColor: "red",  
      };
```

The above code work perfectly normal, however as I was trying to change the background image of the chatbots I assume I would need to pass the styleOptions through styleSet and that is where everything else works normally instead of the upload button despite me setting it to true.

```js
 const styleOptions = {
        hideUploadButton: true,
        bubbleBackground: "red",
        bubbleBorderStyle: "solid",
        bubbleBorderRadius: "10px",
        bubbleFromUserBackground: "#5ce9ff",
        bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: "10px",
        groupTimeStamp: 3000,
        emojiSet: true,
        timestampFormat: 'relative',
        timestampColor: "red",  
      };

      const styleSet = createStyleSet({
        ...styleOptions,
      });

      styleSet.activities = {
        ...styleSet.activities,
        backgroundImage:
          "url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/79/5c/ab/795cabc4647f73b365e2e6eabd0f34dc.png')",
      };
      
      // render webchat
      function renderWebChat(token, userId, enableWSS) {
        console.log("starting webchat");
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
          {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
              token: token,
              // domain: '//' + window.location.host,
              domain:
                "https://bot-web-connector-dot-anna-dev-bot-services.df.r.appspot.com",
              webSocket: !!enableWSS,
            }),
            styleSet,
            store: store,
            userID: userId,
            username: "You",
            locale: navigator.language || "en-SG",
          },
          document.getElementById("webchat")
        );
      }
```

I am not sure why it would not work out when I implement my code this way, could anyone advise me on my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a small bug with `styleOptions`, at the moment. In the mean time, you can do the following to achieve hiding the upload button.

```js
styleSet.uploadButton = {
  ...styleSet.uploadButton,
  display:
    "none",
};
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for helping out, it worked well for me. 
I actually did it through another method by trying to pass the whole styleOptions in the renderWebChat() below styleSet and it kinda worked too.

Nonetheless thanks for helping out so much!

Comment: For a while this seemed to be the fix, but at some point the upload button returned for us. Now I'm looking for a new way to hide the button while using styleSet

Comment: @Martijn, Passing this property and value, `hideUploadButton: true`, straight into `styleOptions` appears to be working correctly now. I just tested with v4.13.0.